# Neo4j spring - Create a 2 way relationship between same type of entities

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Type of relation we want is as follows
CREATE (jack:Person {name:"Jack"})-[:KNOWS]->(jill:Person {name:"Jill"})
WITH jack, jill
CREATE (jack)<-[:KNOWS]-(jill);

How do we model this in the following?

```
@Node
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String email;

    private boolean isActive;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Relationship(type = "Knows", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Knows> knows;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Relationship(type = "Knows", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<Knows> knownBy;  

    public User() {
    }

    public void knows(Knows to) {
        if (knows == null) {
            knows = new HashSet<>();
        }
        knows.add(to);
    }

    public void knownBy(Knows from) {
        if (knownBy == null) {
            knownBy = new HashSet<>();
        }
        knownBy.add(from);
    }
 }
```

```
@RelationshipProperties
public class Knows {

    private String as;

    @CreatedDate
    private Instant createdAt;

    @JsonIgnore
    @TargetNode
    private User User;
}
```

snippet to save the users

```
      User user1 = userRepository.findById(id1);
      User user2 = userRepository.findById(id2);
      Knows knows = new Knows("as", Instant.now(), user1);
            Knows knownBy = new Knows("as", Instant.now(), user2);
            user2.knows(knows);
            user1.knownBy(knownBy);
            userRepository.save(user2);
```

With this, we are getting StackOverflow while saving the User entity.
We want to understand is this the correct way to model it or is there a better way?

Comment: With the current version 6.0.2 of SDN I cannot reproduce the StackOverflow but see a regression regarding bi-directional relationship saves. I am pretty sure that the reason why we fixed this was the StackOverflow. Right now the relationships only get purged but never recreated in the bi-directional mapping scenario.

Comment: I have to correct myself: This bi-directional feature was never supported, so it is not a regression but if it is technical possible, we will fix it.

Comment: so can we achieve this at all or not? I am stuck here on this.

Comment: It is a combination of a bug and a too complicated bidirectional setup IMHO. I have already fixed this but needs merging into the main branches. https://jira.spring.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/DATAGRAPH-1469

Comment: Also if this fix will take a long time then do we have any other way to work this currently. My problem here is, entire modeling of neo4j is done considering this bidirectional relationship, and changing this would change everything for us.

Comment: do you have any ETA of when this will be merged and available for use?

Comment: Basically you should just stick with one knows relationship (outgoing) and fill both ends when you connect the nodes. That would mimic the bidirectional mapping (A knows B and B knows A). But the bug is now in the relationship properties. With a „direct“ relationship from user to user this would work already now. Or you postpone the usage of the bidirectional relationship until the patch is out.

Comment: There is no date set yet. I assume mid January.

Comment: ok, also as far as i see Unidirected relationships are not supported currently right?
also can you elaborate more on "With a „direct“ relationship from user to user this would work already now"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: There is a bug in SDN when it comes to map bidirectional relationships to the database.
Ticket to track is https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-1469
It will be very certain in the next release.

Giving you scenario I would suggest cleaning up the relationships and only create the `OUTGOING` relationships like

```
@Node
public class User {
  // ... id etc.
  @Relationship("KNOWS")
  private List<Knows> knows;
}
```

When it comes to setting the value, both sides need to get populated:

```
user1.knows(user2);
user2.knows(user1);
```

Given the fact that the bug is present until SDN 6.0.3 gets released, I would suggest to either work either unidirected, only connect the `Users` in one direction or link the `Users` directly.
As a consequence you would have no access to the properties on the relationship.

```
@Node
public class User {
  // ... id etc.
  @Relationship("KNOWS")
  private List<User> knows;
}
```

Comment: The second option is out of the question, I need relationship properties. I will wait for SDN 6.0.3. 
With current SDN 
user1.knows(user2);
user2.knows(user1);
this will create StackOverflow correct? I had tried this approach as well and it didn't work so just wanted to clarify this.

Comment: Yes, correct. The usage of the properties in combination with the bidirectional relationship will lead into the StackOverflow on persistence. Btw. you could try out the latest 6.0.3-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Tried 6.0.3 and it doesn't give StackOverflow anymore. I have one question though. Nodes have Outgoing relationships.

Comment: Scenarios 1 -  Node A and B don't have any relation. You add-relation from A-> B and after some time you create a relation from B-> A. This time second B->A is not created.

Comment: Scenarios 2 - Node A and B don't have any relation. You add-relation from A-> B and after some time when you want to create B->A, if you also add A->B again along with B->A. this time it works and creates the relations both ways. 
Why scenario1 is not working, because in scenario2 We need to check if a relationship exists or not and it is an additional find call on the graph, which is sort of unnesscary.